# Extracting embedded JSON from a larger string in Java

Tags: java, json, string, parsing

I have a tool that I'm looking to improve. What it does is parse some data which has some embedded JSON in it. Something like:

```
parse("Keyword1:{\"A\":[1, 2, 3, 4], \"B\":\"SomeString\", \"C\":{\"key\":1234} },Keyword2:whatever");
```

The code knows that when it sees "Keyword1" it should expect some JSON, so I easily know where it starts, but as you can see, not the whole string is JSON and where the JSON ends isn't really that easy to determine without just parsing the JSON.

At the moment, what the code I'm looking at does is consume characters, keeping track of opening and closing '{' and '[' characters, and assumes it's done when it closes the start character.

Which is "fine", but generally doesn't handle things like escaped braces/brackets well at all.

So what I'm looking for is a library that can tell me where the JSON ends. I'm happy with a JSON parser that also just happens to tell me the length of the parsed string or something like that.

Does such a library exist?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to add in a check for being enclosed-in-quotes to your already existing parser? In essence, you have two distinct formats mixed together, but you may also be able to take advantage of the labels not being standard JSON, essentially "splitting" the inputs up by `,\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+:`, and retrieving the labels by operating off the length of the strings in the resulting `#split`.

Comment: Perhaps, I'll have to look into the corner cases of the "outer" format to see if that kind of assumption is always safe.

Comment: I believe the only edge case that would arise is if you are outputting un-quoted json keys (sometimes referred to as minified or prettified, but it _is_ non-standard JSON), in which case I would go back to working on the parser.

Comment: How about just parsing the JSON and catching the exception? Maybe check to see if you have a "{" in the string and if so, find the last index of a closed "}" and then try parsing, If you get an exception, find the next to last index of a closed "}", etc...

Comment: @Rogue, what I mean is that the format I've given is a simplification of the real thing. There are other "interesting" choices in the format that I honestly don't know if they would fit the assumption you've given... but maybe you're idea would work.

Comment: @JonLin That's actually a pretty simple Idea, I could just parse it assuming i'm looking at the correct and, and if it's not, I just search for the next best ending candidate until it succeeds... I'll have to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution I've thought of so far is to use a streaming JSON parser API.

I can use `JsonParser` to read the data in a streaming way. On the first `next()` call I can determine if I'm looking at an object, array, string, number, etc..

And if it's an object, I'll increment an associated counter, on the `START_OBJECT` event and decrement on `END_OBJECT` events. When the counter is `0` I've ingested the whole thing.

Similar for array, though I only need to care about the outermost object of the JSON.

If I use this with a subclass of `StringReader` which tracks how many characters it has read, then I can just ask it, how many characters it consumed while parsing.